# Database tuning and possibly unexpected results

Tags: performance, index, java

(This is cross-posted from stackoverflow; I initially put it in the wrong place.)

So I have a database that's working a bit slower than I would expect and I'd like to describe what I'm doing so hopefully I can verify I'm not missing some performance tweak.  Some details first:

- I'm using java and the database is H2 embedded (although I'm seeing similar results regardless of database).
- I've profiled / timed it and the problems are definitely in the database queries, specifically the executeQuery() call.
- For this example the database table has 60K rows but my query involves a subset of 25K rows yet takes a full 1/2 second to return.

Here's how I've set up the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE rows (
  id @AUTOTYPE@ PRIMARY KEY,

  x VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  y VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  z @TIMETYPE@ NOT NULL
)

CREATE INDEX rows_index ON rows(x, y, z);
```

(Note that the parameterization is for auto increment and timestamp, respectively)

And my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? ORDER BY z DESC
```

Now, I only care about the first row, but it needs to be the newest row, so in java it looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "foo");
stmt.setString(2, "bar");
stmt.setMaxRows(1);
```

Notice the last line has the setMaxRows() set to 1.  To reiterate, the entire 'rows' table has about 60K rows and the query would return 25K rows if I wasn't setting it to return only 1.

So am I doing everything I can?  Even though 1/2s (0.5s) is certainly not a long time it doesn't seem like 60K records should take that long, especially when it should be indexed.  And I know time is relative, so this is just a modern workstation, not running on some sort of load-balanced server.

Thoughts?  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Even if you fetch only 1 row, the database still has to do some extra work, because of the order by and the default ascending index order. While I am not familiar with H2, I think creating the index as (x, y, z desc) should help.

Comment: I googled and found that there is an [EXPLAIN](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html#explain_plan) statement you can use to get the optimizer plan.

compare the following queries

`SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? ORDER BY z DESC`

and

`SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? ORDER BY z` 



The latter should use the index and be faster if the assumptions of   @Balazs Papp are right.
compare to `SELECT * FROM rows WHERE x = ? AND y = ? ` without any sorting.

Comment: @miracle173: I did indeed try to use LIMIT and it didn't make a difference.  I found the H2 docs and it said you can use them interchangeably (i.e., LIMIIT or setMaxRows()).  Thanks for the information about EXPLAIN, I had never heard of it, and it is something I will look into. Thanks!

Comment: @BalazsPapp: I haven't tried an index like that, and didn't know it was possible, but I will give it a shot as I've now seen it in other places.  Thanks!

Comment: I think http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#result_sets says there is no difference between `LIMIT` and `setMaxRows` when using H2

Comment: do you have any results?

Comment: @miracle173: Sorry, as I said at the top, this was cross posted at stack overflow and the selected answer is there.  Basically, the only thing that worked was to use a subquery by selecting the max(z) and it sped up the query by an order of magnitude.  That was good enough for me!

Comment: this is the posting at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546823/database-tuning-and-possibly-unexpected-results